# wordpress testimonials

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization

I have add a testimonial plugin to show the all featured testimonial on my wordpress home, and category pages. But on category page testimonial slider not working properly.
I have also check the JS issue, nothing have to find.
Please give me specified answer. Thanks in advance.

Please specify me where I need to put the testimonials JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seperate the testimonial JS from the default JS code. There may be a JS conflict.
Check for the js folder located at theme/yourtheme/js
Try creating a seperate js file instead of editing in core js file

Comment: thanks, for Ans. please specified me, where i need to add my js file, as i edit my question again